# How to get first column value of DataGridView double clicked row?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I use this `DataTable` as `DataSource` of `GridView`:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID");
table.Columns.Add("Title");
table.Columns.Add("Subject");
...  //filling DataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource=table;
```

I want to get `ID` column value of clicked row of `DataGridView`, so what should I use like this?

```
private void myDataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        //??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, my answer assumes you're working with a `DataGridView` even though you wrote (and tagged) that you're using a `GridView`.

Here's the code you want:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
    var row = myGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    if (row != null) {
        string id = row["ID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This code just takes the `DataRowView` bound to the clicked `DataGridView` row and pulls out its "ID" field value but only if a non-header row is double-clicked.

Now you wrote you want to get ID when the row is clicked and you showed us the [`CellContentDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentdoubleclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handler.  The code above will work when used with `CellContentDoubleClick` but I wonder if you might rather use [`CellDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The difference is that the user would actually have to click a cell's displayed value to fire `CellContentDoubleClick`, but if you use `CellContentDoubleClick` the user would only have to click anywhere on the row (including the row header) to fire the event.  This may make your app a bit easier to use.

Comment: oh! I was in wrong about `DataGridView` and `GridView`! I edited Q!

Answer (score 0):

are u trying to do this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int y = e.RowIndex;
        int x = e.ColumnIndex;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int y1 = e.RowIndex;
        int x1 = e.ColumnIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following code:

```
GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
string columnvalue= gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
```